# Python3 - Format Date in List

Tags: python, python-3.x, strptime

I am currently trying and failing to convert a date ("2017-01-25T09:00") to %Y-%m-%d %H:%M

I tried using strptime() but I get TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not list

Do I need to try it on every item in my list? In the list the date shows up more thank once.

Steps in code:

1. Get response from Rest request in JSON
2. Extract Header values
3. Extract Body line by line
4. Update values with incorrect Date formats to desired format
5. Write each extracted line to spreadsheet

Here is what I am trying at present:

```
    for line in body:
    #newMessageDate = line.get('messagedate')
    if line:
        date_formats = ["%Y-%m-%d%T%H:%M"]
        for date_fmt in date_formats:
            try:
                line = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, date_fmt).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
            except ValueError:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

A trimmed down version of the outputted csv file is as follows:

```
driver,id,startdate,startlocation,finsihlocation,finsihtime
Driver 1,3,2016-09-21T12:02,Dublin,2016-09-21T15:02
Driver 2,4,2016-09-21T12:02,Dublin,2016-09-21T15:02
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post what `line` is?

Comment: In your example you reversed year and day (comparing to your description). `date_formats = ["%d-%m-%Y%T%H:%M"]` instead of this format: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M

Comment: Can you post what  is your `body` data ?

Comment: line is a list in body and body is the body of the rest response returned in json

Comment: So, now you are reading CSV again? Or JSON? Could you decide for one of those?

Comment: Reading JSON, outputting in CSV.

Comment: @user1829517 But why do you show us the output format? It seems not to be relevant at all; after all, your code does not even aggregate the entire output, it's just about converting the date from input. Instead, you should show us the input, i.e. `body` and/or `line`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are reading from a CSV file using a `DictReader`. That means that `line` is a dictionary holding the keys and their values in the current line, as seen in the currently commented line `#newMessageDate = line.get('messagedate')`.

In this case, you should use `line.get('messagedate')` instead of `line` itself.

```
newMessageDate = line.get('messagedate')
newMessageDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(newMessageDate, date_fmt).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

(I'm skipping the loop and the `try/except` as those are unchanged.)

---

Unfortunately, you do not state how exactly `line` looks. From latest comments, it seems like you do not read CSV but JSON, and that `line` is a `list` instead of a `dict`. In this case, you have to access the date element using the respective index, e.g. `newMessageDate = line[3]` (assuming that the date is in the fourth position of the list). The rest of the answer still holds.

Comment: And if you are not using a dict reader but a regular CSV reader (as might be hinted by the `get` lines being commented), then `line` would be a list; in this case, get the correct element from that list, e.g. `newMessageDate = line[3]` or whatever.

Comment: Hi Tobias, 

I am reading from a rest request that returns in JSON.

Comment: The commented out line is from an example I found online that reads from a csv

Comment: @user1829517 Well, the same principle still applies: `line` is a `list` or `dict` and you have to extract the correct value, using the correct index or key.

Comment: When I added your suggestion I get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

A trimmed down version of what I saved extraction is added above

Comment: @user1829517 Yes, becasuse I assumed it's a dict based on your code. If it's a list, you have to use `line[3]` or whatever is the position of the date field in the list.